# How to change TextBlock Text from codebehind?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a custom control. There is a Stack Panel with Button and TextBlock in generic.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
<TextBlock x:Name="StatusText" />
</StackPanel>
```

Then I have

```
public class MyClass : Control
{
// Constructor etc.

public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("StatusText", typeof(TextBlock), typeof(MyClass), null);

public TextBlock StatusText
{
get { return (TextBlock)this.GetValue(StatusTextProperty); }
set { SetValue(StatusTextProperty, value); }
}
}
```

There is if with some logic in that happens after the button is clicked.
How do I change the Text property of TextBloc?
I thought that I can do something like this

```
StatusText.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "Some text here.");
```

But it always returns NullReferenceException (Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Should I use PropertyChangedCallback() on dependency property or what else do I need? I am missing something ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're taking the wrong approach - instead of trying to *push* the text into the text block from the control's class, you need the text block to *pull* the value from the control's class.  The main steps you need to do are:

1. Change the type of the dependency property from TextBlock to string.
2. Bind the Text property of the TextBlock in your control template to the dependency property using a TemplateBinding binding expression.  Something along the lines of:

   <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding StatusText}" />

You can then simply set the text to be displayed to the property on your control.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Comment: what if the text was already bound, and I wanted to get the current value of the textblock inside a stackpanel?

Answer (score -6):

You can type your question on google and find answer few times faster.

Comment: Have you noticed the results that Google finds is this question on SO? :-)

Comment: SO is a specialist version of Google, with a rating system etc. The quality of answers here is much higher. What are you even doing here if Google has all the answers?

Comment: Dear @ProfK
I nevers wrote that google has all answers :) 
But lots of questions can be easily found there, and this was one of them.